# Printing only the letters by ABC order from String

Tags: java

I couldn't really explain myself in the title, what I meant is - get a String and check every letter and print it if the next char in the String is also the next letter in the ABC order, for example "almndrefg" will return "lmnefg", what I did so far is :

```
    package strings;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class P58Targil7 {
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String st2 = in.next();
        check(st2);
    }

    public static void check(String st1) {
        char sec,fir;
        for (int i = 0; i < st1.length() - 1; i++) {
            sec = st1.charAt(i + 1);
            fir = st1.charAt(i);
            sec--;
            if (fir == sec)
                System.out.print(fir);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I correct?

Comment: keep an array of all possible chars (26, or 52, if you want A and a to be treated differently), and check therein whether one was already printed.

Comment: How's "lmnefg" in ABC order?

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: Do you mean sort the given word in alphabetical order? You need to explain your question clearly.

Comment: @MarounMaroun lmn , efg ..

Comment: @user3437460 Its hard for me to explain because of my English but no, I meant it will check every letter inside the String and return this letter if the next char is the next letter by the ABC order.

Comment: Is what you're trying to do: "strip out characters that aren't preceded by the letter that precedes it in the alphabet?" That is, if a "b" is not after an "a", it gets stripped.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 Do you mean print runs of 2 or more letters which are in alphabetical order?

Comment: @JuanMendes I found my problem, instead of sec++; I changed to sec--; but now if I put abc it will return only ab.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I will edit and explain myself better.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1 I got what you mean but, why is `n` printed when the next letter in the String is `d` ?

Comment: @user3437460 Because it is after the letter 'm' (for mnd) it will still print mn and not just m..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a small mistake, since you incremented `sec` instead of `fir`.

In addition, you must handle the printing of the second letter in each consecutive pair, and make sure each letter is only printed once.

```
    char sec,fir;
    boolean lastPrinted = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < st1.length() - 1; i++) {
        fir = st1.charAt(i);
        sec = st1.charAt(i + 1);
        if (fir + 1 == sec) {
            if (!lastPrinted) {
                System.out.print(fir);
            }
            System.out.print(sec);
            lastPrinted = true;
        } else {
            lastPrinted = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never reset lastPrinted to false on the (non-existent) else statement. Also, consider using curly brackets for ifs, even if it contains only one instruction, as this leads to fewer errors when later editing or reading.

Comment: Thanks, I found the mistake and fixed it but it still not working, I copied your code and for the String abcomn it returns only abcn , it doesn't include the M , what should I do next? תודה גבר :P

Comment: In that case, consider giving this man a cookie. or at least, accepting his answer :)

Comment: @AdrianB. Sure, I couldn't because 15 minutes hadn't passed yet :)